# Java high precision stopwatch

Tags: java, stopwatch

I have this problem, and I can't get any idea how to solve it.
I have to measure the time needed to perform certain function. Okay, stopwatch function that measure time in milliseconds wasn't good enough, so I used measurement in nano seconds.

The problem is, function ends so fast, even stopwatch in nano seconds can't measure it.

I know that stopwatch works, because I tried to put for example `Thread.sleep(1)` in my function (Thread.sleep is in milliseconds), and I get my time, but without `Thread.sleep`, my time is always 0. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
long startTimeLocalNS=0;
long stopTimeLocalNS = 0;
startTimeLocalNS = System.nanoTime();
if (something)
{
    /*my Code;*/
}   
stopTimeLocalNS = System.nanoTime();
disconnectTime = (stopTimeLocalNS - startTimeLocalNS);
```

Comment: If the time is 0, you don't have a very accurate nanoTime() clock on your system.  if I do `long time = System.nanTime() - System.nanoTime()` on my system its is typically 100 or more. (because thats how long the call takes)

Comment: Are you sure `something` == true ?

Comment: If it takes such a short period of time, why do you care how long it takes? Microbenchmarks tend to use loops (after warm up). More useful benchmarks do something useful.

Comment: Is it possible that something's optimizing the second call away and just using the first value?

Comment: @Peter Yes, something == true, that's 100%. I will search for precision of my nano clock on the system. That should help.

@Tom Well, I need that time. If I don't, I wouldn't ask for help... =]

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: re: `if I do time = System.nanTime() - System.nanoTime() on my system its is typically 100 or more` - that's strange, on mine I always get a negative number :)

Comment: Can you tell us a bit about the function that is taking so little time to run?

Comment: @Rich, good point. It should be `long start = System.nanoTime(); long time = System.nanoTime() - start` cheers.

Comment: .. and why if its so fast that you have trouble measuring, that you still need to measure it.

Comment: @CRT_flow, dead code elimination?

Comment: @bestsss: Even if all the code between the two times were eliminated, even a call to an empty subroutine takes at least a nanosecond even for native code.  A call to `System.nanoTime()` would take a bit more, meaning even `System.nanoTime() - System.nanoTime()` should be nonzero.

Comment: @cHao, that depends on the underlying OS and hardware, precisely how precise System.nanoTime() is. Also java tends to inline stuff for hot code and -server (hotspot) inlines quite well (so often no subroutines are called).

Answer (score 7):

How about running the function a few thousand (or million) times in a loop, measuring the total time and dividing it by the number of iterations?

But beware the many [pitfalls in writing microbenchmarks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02225.html).

Comment: Well, my function is a bit specific, and can't be run more than 1 time. But, if I always get time that my nano clock can't measure, and I divide it by number of iterations, I would have 0 time again?

Comment: @CRT_flow: not sure what you mean by that. And your requirements sound rather nonsensical. I'll go so far as to say that it's impossible that you cannot run the function more than once.

Comment: I think that @CRT_flow is thinking that you time each invokation of the method.

Comment: @CRT_flow: Michael is suggesting that you time the total time for X million invokations, and divide that by the number of invokations. He's not suggesting that you invoke it X million times and time each invokation.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
long startTimeLocalNS=0;
long stopTimeLocalNS = 0;
int count = 10000;
startTimeLocalNS = System.nanoTime();
if (something)
{
    while(count-- != 0) {
    /*my Code;*/
    }
}   
stopTimeLocalNS = System.nanoTime();
disconnectTime = (stopTimeLocalNS - startTimeLocalNS) / count;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the to-be-measured code 1000 times, then divide the nanoTime-difference by 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Are you profiling some code? If so, profiles available on the market will do a much better job.

If you just need to measure very short period of time, You have several options:

- `System.currentTimeMillis()` - on my computer it has a 60Hz resolution, which gives about 16ms granularity
- `System.nanoTime()` - suppose to be more accurate, but I heard that in the age of multi-core CPUs it's not the fastest solution
- JNI - measure the time in C, but the cost of JNI invocation will be significant.

Comment: can you mention a few profilers available? preferably open source?

Comment: Sure, jvisualvm is free and has a built-in profiler (but I never tried it). I know JProfiler is very good, many people also suggest Yourkit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to benchmark your function easiest way is to run it several times inside one measurement. Then divide time by amount of calls.

Comment: As I said, my function is specific and can be measured only once... Plus, it would take longer to finish my program, so it's a bit messy solution, imho.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a very different answer depending on whether the JVM is warmed up or not. For very short sequences which you will be calling many times. You should time how long it takes to repeat them.

Answer (score 0):

An answer out of left field: as Peter Lawrey states, most systems should be returning a number greater than zero for a result when comparing two calls to `nanoTime()`. However, are you absolutely certain that you are comparing the right values? Could you accidentally be doing this:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
if (something)
{
    /*my Code;*/
}
long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
disconnectTime = stopTime - stopTime; //note the error - you are subtracting stoptime from itself
```

So, my question is, is there a bug in your code that you've not reproduced in the sample code above?

Second question, are you certain that `something==true`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that my if statement is true, and I didn't do stopTime - stopTime =]

Comment: Cool - thought I'd just ask :)

Comment: is there a way i can pause a stop watch for sometime and continue the timer.Havn't found any suitable answer.